# How to scroll through a UIACollectionView and click on a button?

Tags: ui-automation, appium, scrollto, ios-ui-automation

I'm trying to perform a scrollTo method within UIACollectionView control , but with no much success so far , I've tried to use TouchAction.

Any idea how I can perform a scrollTo ?

java_client 2.2.0
appium 1.3.6
IOS 8.1

Answer (score 0):

First just look for the String on the bottom of the screen where you want to scroll. And then use `scrollTo(String)`

Comment: The thing is  , the string I'm trying to scroll to is located on the upper side of the screen , while I'm trying to scroll to it , nothing actually happens although the scrollTo command being executed in appium's shell